# How to write a grep regular expression such that a certain string does not appear anywhere before the matching pattern on the current line?

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to find all instances of statements like

```
             ABCD.Transaction = GlobalCommArea 
      WXY.Transaction = GlobalCommArea 
         PQR.Transaction = LMN.Transaction
    DEF.XYZ(CStr(i)).Transaction = GlobalCommArea
```

The only thing I want to avoid is the presence of a single quote before any of these statements.

So, for eg.

```
      ' PQR.Transaction = GlobalCommArea
```

would be invalid, but

```
       WXY.Transaction = GlobalCommArea ' 2012
```

would be valid, because the quote comes after the matching part on the line

If the single quote problem didn't exist, I could write a simple regex as follows -

```
      grep -nr  "\.Transaction" .
```

How to write a regex that could ensure that there is no single quote anywhere on the line before the match?

Comment: Added note: I am running this on GNU grep 2.6.3
 on Cygwin on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -nrE "^[^']+\.Transaction"
```

Comment: Are you sure you added the `-e` switch?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which flavor of grep you're using, but GNU grep 2.9 (on my Ubuntu box), will do this (the `-P` switch turns on PCRE, so the lookahead works):

```
grep -P "^(?! *').+Transaction.+$" file_to_search.txt
```

Explained:

```
^              # start at beginning of line
(?! *')        # negative lookahead for optional space and a single quote
.+Transaction  # one or more characters up to 'Transaction'
.+$            # all remaining character up to end of line
```

**Edit: shown working on cygwin**

```
$ uname -r        
1.7.11(0.260/5/3)   # cygwin ver. 1.7.11

$ grep --version
GNU grep 2.6.3

$ cat foo.txt       # contents of the file I'm grepping
  ABCD.Transaction = ' GlobalCommArea
'   WXY.Transaction = GlobalCommArea
  PQR.Transaction = LMN.Transaction
     '  DEF.XYZ(CStr(i)).Transaction = GlobalCommArea

$ grep -P "^(?! *').+Transaction.+$" foo.txt
ABCD.Transaction = ' GlobalCommArea
PQR.Transaction = LMN.Transaction
```

Comment: What are you running it on? What version of grep? What OS? It works for me on Ubuntu 11.10 and GNU grep 2.9.

Comment: GNU grep 2.6.3 on Cygwin on Windows 7

Comment: CodeBlue, see edit. It works for me on Cygwin as well. I'm running Cygwin on XP, but don't know why that would matter. I also tested the answer given by @kev. It works on Cygwin as well (not shown above).